# init.d service doesn't start

Tags: boot, ubuntu-12.04, services, daemon

I have installed `ushare`and want to start is with booting. `sudo service ushare start`works, and there is a link to start ushare in /etc/rc2.d (and also rc3, rc4, rc5) and there are stop links in other folders.

But after system start `ps ax | grep ushare` shows ushare is not running.

What could go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

We should enable the service to start at run level. To check ushare is enabled as a service at runlevels

Check **chkconfig --l ushare** in command prompt.

**ushare                 0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off**

If it is not set on then you need to set ushare to be started on boot.

**chkconfig ushare on**

Otherwise use **update-rc.d** command to enable or disable a service at a run level:

> $update-rc.d ushare defaults

Comment: the output is as you posted, yet it still doesn't work

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: `update-rc.d` just tells me that the links already exist.

Comment: try once **$sudo update-rc.d -f ushare remove**  and again **$update-rc.d ushare defaults**

Comment: Just tried it, still doesn't start up. I wonder if I should try starting ushare via cron.